# Finding left and right cosets of $H=\{e,f\}$ and of $K=\{e,r,r^{2},r^{3}\}$ in $D_{4}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I would like to verify my answers.
[image]

EDIT: After reading comments below by pjs36, this is my second attempt:

[image]

EDIT (again): A few mistakes still exist in the second attempt. It should be $rH=\{r,rf\}$ and $r^{2}H=\{r^{2},r^{2}f\}$ and $r^{3}H=\{r^{3},r^{3}f\}$.

Comment: $K$ is normal in $D_4$, so it should turn out that $gK = Kg$ for all $g \in D_4$. So something appears off there. Also in $Kfr$, you have $f$ listed twice.

Comment: Thank you for the input.  I re-did it (above) and the patterns look more consistent now

Comment: They do, but things still seem a bit funny with $H$. I think your cosets depend on how $f$ is defined (there are a couple different reflections that could be $f$), but either way, if $rH = \{r, fr\}$, that would imply $rf = fr$. I don't there's a choice of reflection $f$ that makes that true. So I wonder if you have $gH$ and $Hg$ reversed? Or maybe you're following a convention I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Oh yeah... you are right. I think that I just wrote it backwards, and likewise with the few cosets following that one. So, I think it should be $rH=\{r,rf\}$ and $r^{2}H=\{r^{2},r^{2}f\}$ and $r^{3}H=\{r^{3},r^{3}f\}$. These problems are just so tedious/confusing for me it's hard to concentrate; I make lots of little mistakes. But I get the idea, I always need a second pair of eyes!